# How to find IP address of a device connected on LAN, if MAC address is known. Device is an embedded system

Tags: vb.net, networking, tcp, embedded

I want to communicate to an embedded system using VB.net whose MAC address is marked on it but No idea about it's IP address. Even the IP address could be out of subnet range. If the IP address is outside subnet range will it be possible to communicate with it on port 10001?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have triesd using ARP but it works only if IP address is reachable i.e. the IP is in the same subnet. I am using XPORT from lantronix which comes with a software called as device installer, which can locate XPORT connected on a lan network. I want to do similar jon using my VB/VB.NET program so as to make it easy.

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on your LAN router and on how you connect your embedded device to the LAN router.  In this answer, I use my home LAN router as an example --- look up your own router's documentation to adapt each step to your own setting.

Most LAN routers act as DHCP servers and automatically assign an IP addresses whenever you connect a device to the router.  Most LAN routers have a web user interface --- you can login and manage the router.  We just want to find out which IP addresses are assigned by the DHCP server.

My D-Link router can be accessed through browsing `http://10.0.0.138/` and logging in as user `Admin`.  In the menu, I select 'Device Info' and then 'DHCP'.  There, the router shows a table of all connected devices: their MAC addresses and IP addresses.  This is the information that you are looking for.

My router also allows me to choose which IP address should be assigned to which MAC address.  This can be configured below `Advanced Setup`, `LAN` and `Static IP Lease List`.

Of course, you must consult the manual of **your** router to find out the correct URL to access your admin account, the correct password for to login.  Also, your routers web user interface may differ from what I have.  But I hope that this info helps you to start your search for the IP address.